# using global value in FreeRTOS inside a Timer ISR

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, freertos, isr

Using:

- Arduino Mega 2560
- Arduino IDE
- Timer2

Code:

```
#include "FreeRTOS_AVR.h"
#include "basic_io_avr.h"

/*** 
* HITEC servo ranges from 0.9 to 2.4 ms
* values in usec 
***/

const int firstPulse = 0.7 * 1000;
const int centerPulse = 1.5 * 1000;
const int lastPulse = 2.4 * 1000;
const int cycleLength = 20 * 1000;
const int degree = (lastPulse - firstPulse) / 180 * 1.0; //9.44
const int SERVO_PIN = 29;
const int ULTRASOON_PIN = 43;

void servoTask(void* p);
void ultrasoonTask(void* p);
void receiveTask(void* p);

QueueHandle_t xQueueDistance, xQueueDegrees;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    cli();
    USART_init();
    Timer2_init();
    Timer3_init();
    sei();
    pinMode(SERVO_PIN, OUTPUT);

    xQueueDistance = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(uint8_t));
    xQueueDegrees = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(int));

    xTaskCreate(servoTask, "Servo task", 200, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(ultrasoonTask, "Ultrasoon task", 200, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(receiveTask, "Receive task", 200, NULL, 1, NULL); 
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    while(1) {writeString("DEAD LOOP\n");};
}

volatile int pulse=0;
ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect) {
  static int x=0;

  x++;
  if(x%2) {
   //vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", pulse);
   //moveServo(pulse);
  }
}

ISR( TIMER3_COMPA_vect){}

void ultrasoonTask(void* p) {
  uint8_t ultrasoonValue; 
  portBASE_TYPE xStatus;

  while(1) {
    ultrasoonValue = ping();
    //vPrintStringAndNumber("Ping= ", ultrasoonValue);
    xQueueSendToBack(xQueueDistance, &ultrasoonValue, 0);
    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

void servoTask(void *p) { 
  uint8_t inValue;
  int m_degrees;
  portBASE_TYPE xStatus;

  while(1) {
    xStatus = xQueueReceive(xQueueDistance, &inValue, 0);
    if(xStatus == pdPASS) {
      //vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoRead= ", inValue);
      m_degrees = changeServoPosition((int)inValue);
      //vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", m_degrees);
      xQueueSendToBack(xQueueDegrees, &m_degrees, 0);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

void receiveTask(void* p) {
  int m_degrees; 
  portBASE_TYPE xStatus;

  while(1) {
    xStatus = xQueueReceive(xQueueDegrees, &m_degrees, 0);
    if(xStatus == pdPASS) {
      //vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", m_degrees);
      pulse = m_degrees;
      //vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", pulse);
    }
    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

long ping() {
  pinMode(ULTRASOON_PIN, OUTPUT); // Switch signalpin to output
  digitalWrite(ULTRASOON_PIN, LOW); // Send low pulse
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Wait for 2 microseconds
  digitalWrite(ULTRASOON_PIN, HIGH); // Send high pulse
  delayMicroseconds(5); // Wait for 5 microseconds
  digitalWrite(ULTRASOON_PIN, LOW); // Holdoff

  pinMode(ULTRASOON_PIN, INPUT); // Switch signalpin to input  
  digitalWrite(ULTRASOON_PIN, HIGH); // Turn on pullup resistor

  long temp = pulseIn(ULTRASOON_PIN, HIGH); //Listen for echo

  //convert to CM: sound speed is 340 m/s. 29microseconds/cm. 
  //                 ping signal travels out and back, take half distance travelled.
  return temp / 29 / 2;
}

void moveServo(int p) {
    digitalWrite(SERVO_PIN, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(p);
    digitalWrite(SERVO_PIN, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(cycleLength - p);
}

int changeServoPosition(int in) {
  int p = in * degree + firstPulse;
  if(p < firstPulse) {
    p = firstPulse;
  } else if(p > lastPulse) {
    p = lastPulse;
  }
  return p;
}

void Timer2_init() {
  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;
  //  CTC Mode
  TCCR2B |= (1<<WGM22);
  //
  //  Prescaler mode: 1024
  TCCR2B |= (1<<CS22) | (1<<CS20);

  TIMSK2 = (1<<OCIE2A); //interrupt enable
  TCNT2 = 0;
  OCR2A = 156;
}

/**
  *  Timer3 is 16 bits, max tellen tot 2^16= 65535 
  *  OCR3A = FCPU / prescaler / frequentie
  *  FCPU = 16000000, Prescaler = 1024, FCPU/Prescaler = 15625
  *  Frequentie = 1/(time in seconds), 20ms = 0.02s, 1/s = 50Hz
  *  OCR3A = 312.5
  **/

void Timer3_init() {
  TCCR3A = 0;
  TCCR3B = 0;

  //  CTC Mode
  TCCR3B |= (1<<WGM32);  
  //  Prescaler mode: 1024
  TCCR3B |= (1<<CS32) | (1<<CS30);

  TIMSK3 = (1<<OCIE3A); //interrupt enable
  TCNT3 = 0;
  OCR3A = 313;
}

void USART_init() {
  /* Set baud rate */
  UBRR0H = 0;//UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
  UBRR0L = 16000000/16/9600-1; //FCPU en BAUD. UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
  UCSR0A = 0;
  /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
  UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
  /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
  UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);  // URSEL: Register select, om op UCSRC te schrijven
                // USBS:  op 2stop bit zetten
                // UCSZ0: 3 erop schuiven, hierdoor UCSZ0 en UCSZ1 op 1 geset. 8 bit
}

void writeChar(char data){
  /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
  while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );    // UDRE is een flag die wacht totdat data in de buffer gezet mag worden.
    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = (uint8_t)data;
}

void writeString(char* str){
  while(*str)
    writeChar(*str++);
}

void writeInteger(int16_t number, uint8_t base){
  char nmb[3];
  itoa(number, nmb, base);
  writeString(nmb);
}

char readChar(){
  /* Wait for data to be received */
  while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) );      // RXC is een flag die wacht totdat er data bij de buffer van de ontvanger is.
  /* Get and return received data from buffer */
    return (char)UDR0;
}

void loop(){
}
```

Problem:

`volatile int pulse` is a global variable I want to use in the ISR of Timer2.
With the `receiveTask`, I get the value from a queue and set it as the pulse value.

But every time the value of pulse is 0.

Comment: Are you sure the `pulse` variable is actually updated in the `receiveTask` function?

Comment: Yes. If I uncomment vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", m_degrees); it shows numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the [xQueueReceive()](http://www.freertos.org/a00118.html) function looks correct, so assuming the if( xStatus == pdPASS ) test is actually passing, then I would assume that the problem is actually where you are posting a value to the queue, not where you are receiving the value.  You don't show that code though.  Are you sure you are actually writing to the queue, and that the value being written to the queue is not always 0?

Comment: Yes. If I uncomment vPrintStringAndNumber("ServoPos= ", m_degrees); it shows numbers.